# SerialPort won't send Data. buffers it somewhere. data gets pushed out when other program sends data over the same port

Tags: c#, serial-port

Sorry for possible wrong spelling i'm not a native english speaker.

Software written in C# with VisualStudio Community 2015 and .net 4.0.
Reading Serial communication with Free Device Monitoring Studio.

USB to RS232 Dongle LogiLink FTDI-Chipset due to no RS232 port available on Notebook.

```
namespace Serial_Test
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender,  System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((SerialPort1.IsOpen == true))
            {
                SerialPort1.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort1.PortName = "COM5";
            SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
            SerialPort1.DataBits = 8;
            SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            SerialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;

            if ((SerialPort1.IsOpen == false))
            {
                SerialPort1.Open();
            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((SerialPort1.IsOpen == true))
            {
                SerialPort1.Write(" --Aus C#-- ");
                MessageBox.Show("Data send");
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((SerialPort1.IsOpen == true))
            {
                SerialPort1.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This runs without any errors but won't send Data.
**But it won't even echo data from a serial port that is not connected to anything.**

Then, after closing my program and sending data from any other program (in this case self written VBS) over the same COM port it will send the data that should have been sent before attached to the new data.

[explanation picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLY1N.jpg)

I tried 3 different dongles allready (from 20€ to 200€) and got the same problem over and over again.

Comment: Your Handshake property assignment is just wrong.  Selecting None is almost never correct, the vast majority of devices use RequestToSend.  If for some very mysterious reason None is actually intended then you have to set the DtrEnable and RtsEnable properties to *true* yourself.

Comment: @Hans Passant
Thank you  for your help. I tried to enable and disable Dtr and Rts. It didn´t work.
On a different machine (same OS) my script is running all fine!

In a book from Dr. John Allwork ( VS C# 2010 Programming ) he sais that for USB to Serial Dongles I should use "quote: "... something like COM port 17."  Did anyone hear about that before?
p.s. COM 15 - 20 Didn´t work either.

Comment: Additional information. I´m not even getting an echo over a COM port thats not connected to anything, so I'm far away from thinking about any Device's settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling `.Flush` off of your serial port instance. That clears any buffers.

Comment: A. white
I´m trying to send the (somehow) buffered data all the way out. Flushing would just get rid of it, i guess.

Comment: I tried something:
open C# -> Send Data --- nothing happens (COM sniffer)
C# -> bytestowrite = 0 -> anyways .discardOUTBuffer -> close C#
open VBS -> Send Data --- C# data AND VBS data gets send out

I have no idea where the C# Data gets stuck.

Comment: @AndreasM flush is not to remove it - its to send the data and clear the buffer

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I tried to flush the Port with .BaseStream.Flush right after the .WriteLine command. It did't work.
At no time there are .BytesToWrite. I guess thats why the .Flush is uneffective.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

This didn't work:

```
_SP.Write("VERSION?" + "\r");
```

This works all fine!

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[9];

        buffer[0] = 0x56;
        buffer[1] = 0x45;
        buffer[2] = 0x52;
        buffer[3] = 0x53;
        buffer[4] = 0x49;
        buffer[5] = 0x4f;
        buffer[6] = 0x4e;
        buffer[7] = 0x3f;
        buffer[8] = 0x0d;

        string text = buffer.ToString();
        _SP.Write(buffer,0,9);
```

Serial Port settings stayed the same.
Can somebody explain this behaviour?